# Domain name being removed from URL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 and my application is being odd.  I startup my web application and get redirected to the login page just fine, but once I login, it attempts to redirect to Default.aspx.  This wouldn't normally be a problem, but the domain is being removed on redirect and therefore, it is causing an error.  If I put the domain name back into the url, I get the page I was expecting.

Example
This is what I'm expecting after login.

```
http://localhost:8080/Default.aspx
```

What I'm getting after login is this:

```
http://Default.aspx
```

I'm thinking there is an issue in my VS setup, IIS Express, or an error in my Web.config, but not sure where to look.

EDIT:  This only happens with this webapp.  I have other webapp projects that I work on and it doesn't occur in those.  That leads me to believe the issue is more likely a setting that is off in either VS, the project, or my Web.config.

EDIT:  For added clarification, after login, any link/button that I click causes this error to occur.  I have to add the domain every time I navigate to a new page.  This leads me to believe the error is not actually caused by the login itself.

Comment: add relevant login code,, check if you have prefix forward slash at beginning of redirect url.

Comment: Is this web forms or mvc or what? If mvc you should probably be using Url.Content.

Comment: This is using webforms.

Comment: post relevant code Daniel, are you sure in redirect there's no something wrong ?

Comment: I'm new to this project.  It looks like we are generating the URL.  I'm trying to find the code for that URL generation(very large codebase).  The strange thing is that we have this code in other environments and it's working just fine.  Once I find the code for the URL generation, I'll update my post with it.

Comment: It looks like the app is generating the URL as //Default.aspx?parameters.

Comment: Looks like the navigation is related to the generation of the URL.  I can't change the library that's generating the URL, as it's in use in all the webapps, but I might be able to create a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't an issue in the code.  The issue was in IIS Express itself.  To fix my issue, I switched to using my local IIS server instead.[image]

I set the specific page, switched the sever to Local IIS, and then set the project URL and created a virtual directory in IIS.

This solved the URL resolving to \\Default.aspx.